# How to distribute spaces between text views of linear layout to fit according to different text lengths

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, textview, android-linearlayout

In the Image attached below, the red box represents the linear layout.

In each linear layout I have 2 children text views to display details. Text on the text views are getting filled from JSON data fetched from google books api.

What I am finding difficult is how to maintain space between both the text views according to different text length.

Like in the 5th list item "Fundamental Of Java..." can be extended more as there is many space left.

In the 1st item item Both Title and Author name is really long so both should be displayed equally (50-50)%

And in the 3rd list item "Pearson Education..."  can be extended more as there is more blank space  before it.

So How to can determine/Distribute space in layout which fits each situations.

> Code Of Linear Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Java Programming is really long text right not"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/publisher"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="John Wiley and its going long &amp; Sons"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10sp"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try experimenting using **RelativeLayout** on your xml but you have to give priority on which **textView** that will consume most of the space -  either of the two ( title or the publisher) then add a **autoSizeTextType** on your **textView**.
    You can also use **ConstraintLayout** but you have to limit the number of items to be displayed in your **recyclerview**, or create a function that detects if the particular string consist of "n" characters long then adjust a padding or margin.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/publisher"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Java Programming is really long text right not Java"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/publisher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="John Wiley &amp; Sons sdafsdfsfsdf"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```